# python recursive generator fail

Tags: python, json, recursion, nested-loops, yield

I've got nested json object it contains lists and dicts.. and I want to search it for all 'foo' keys inside.
I'm trying to do recursive generator but function fail on second call of parse dunno why, I even see 'in' output only once. Looks like interpreter do not get inside parse second time etc.. Help me understand where I'am wrong?

```
def parse(d,key):
    print('in')
    if type(d)==type({}):
        if key in d:
            yield d[key]
        for k in d:
            parse(d[k],key)
    if type(d)==type([]):
        for i in d:
            parse(i,key)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generators don't quite work like coroutines. If a generator function recursively calls itself, the recursive call produces another generator object. Control doesn't reenter the generator code like it would in something like Lua, and a `yield` won't suspend a whole stack of generator calls at once. You have to iterate over the returned generator object and yield its elements:

```
def parse(d,key):
    print('in')
    if type(d)==type({}):
        if key in d:
            yield d[key]
        for k in d:
            for item in parse(d[k],key):
                yield item
    if type(d)==type([]):
        for i in d:
            for item in parse(i,key):
                yield item
```

In Python 3.3, the `yield from` syntax for delegating to a subgenerator was added, so the code would reduce to the following:

```
def parse(d,key):
    print('in')
    if type(d)==type({}):
        if key in d:
            yield d[key]
        for k in d:
            yield from parse(d[k],key)
    if type(d)==type([]):
        for i in d:
            yield from parse(i,key)
```

This has the advantage of automatically handling `send`, `throw`, and a bunch of edge cases that explicitly looping over the subgenerator doesn't deal with.